# Uso de servicios google maps

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy programando una aplicación de Android donde se utilizan los servicios de google maps. Quisiera saber si puedo buscar la latitud y longitud. ingresando el nombre de algún lugar en un editText, ejemplo: "Hospitales", y me traiga. ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien sabe cómo hacerlo. me podria compartir documentacion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para eso puedes implementar `Google Places` tiene muy buena [documentacion](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/places/?apis=places)

Cabe mencionar que debes tener tarjeta de crédito para una cuenta de facturación.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]

Comment: Pero igual yo puedo hacer pruebas sin pagar?

Comment: Las pruebas si, pero siempre para poder usar el sdk te piden la tarjeta de credito